# Combining two ActiveRecord models into one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

A Rails application I'm developing has two models: `Review` and `Interview`. They are both essentially articles, but they are different in their attributes and behaviors.

Some of the application's pages need to display reviews and interviews together, as if they were from the same model. This means that I somehow need to bring them together into one model and then use said model as a "proxy".

I achieved a basic result by implementing an `Article` model with the following code:

```
class Article
  MODELS = [Review, Interview]

  def self.fetch(&block)
    block = Proc.new { all } unless block_given?
    results = []

    MODELS.each do |model|
      suppress(StandardError) do
        results.push(*model.class_eval(&block))
      end
    end

    results
  end
end
```

This offers me the basic functionality I need. I can now use something like `Article.fetch { where("created_at >= ?", 10.days.ago.to_date) }` and the same query will be run on both models, giving me an array of results (not sorted by date, but actually with reviews and interviews chunked together, as they come from two different queries).

This approach seems to work, but it also has some important drawbacks.
A big one is that any kind of sorting must be implemented manually after the query if you want results to be sorted properly.

I have no problem with implementing my own methods to work around the issues I encounter, but I'm wondering if there's a more *standard* way to achieve this in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your problem, you have basically two models with different attributes and behaviours.

One approach would be to create a parent class with 2 sub class inherit from the parent class.

`class Article`

`class Review < Article` & `class Interview < Article`

Using the single-table inheritance (STI) approach, you just create a type column that will differentiate the two and have validations and columns populate based on the sub class.

Comment: Would I have to have all the columns necessary to both models on the same table, too?

Comment: If you need them on the same table yes and validation will be based on the class